# How to get rid of instanceOf implementing Firebase registration using RxJava

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, rx-java, rx-java2

We are trying to implement Firebase Authorization using RxAndroid library.

The problem is all own implementations ends with `instanceOf`. We are trying to get rid of them. I feel ̶d̶i̶s̶t̶u̶r̶b̶a̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶c̶e̶ that we are using Rx paradigm in a wrong way. Finally, we decided to use a wrapper library.

We found a [library](https://github.com/kunny/RxFirebase) that already implemented wrappers for the Firebase library. But implementation is also fell into `instanceOf` routine.

Here is an example of implementation using [library](https://github.com/kunny/RxFirebase):

```
public void resendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber) {

    final Disposable disposable = RxPhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
            PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance(),
            phoneNumber, // Phone number to verify
            60,  // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,  // Unit of timeout
            (Activity) mAuthenticationView,
            forceResendingToken)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::phoneVerificationSuccess, this::phoneVerificationError);

    mCompositeDisposable.add(disposable);
}
```

And here is success handler:

```
private void phoneVerificationSuccess(PhoneAuthEvent phoneAuthEvent){
   if (phoneAuthEvent instanceof PhoneAuthCodeSentEvent) {
       verificationId = ((PhoneAuthCodeSentEvent) phoneAuthEvent).verificationId();
       forceResendingToken = ((PhoneAuthCodeSentEvent) phoneAuthEvent).forceResendingToken();

       mAuthenticationView.showCodeSent();
   }
   if (phoneAuthEvent instanceof PhoneAuthVerificationCompleteEvent) {
       PhoneAuthCredential credential = ((PhoneAuthVerificationCompleteEvent) phoneAuthEvent).credential();
       mAuthenticationView.showVerifySuccess(credential);
       signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
   }
```

}

Here is error handler:

```
private void phoneVerificationError(Throwable throwable) {
    if (throwable instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
        // Invalid request
        mAuthenticationView.showInvalidPhoneNumber();
    } else if (throwable instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
        // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
        mAuthenticationView.showSMSQuotaExceeded();
    }

    mAuthenticationView.showVerificationFailedError(throwable.getMessage());
}
```

Please tell us what we are doing wrong? I feel that `instanceOf` smells bad, but I can't find any other way to implement Firebase using Rx.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to simply eliminate `instanceof` at any cost, you could do something like this (generalized form).

The class hierarchy:

```
class Thing {}
class FooThing extends Thing {}
class BarThing extends Thing {}
```

Create a dispatch table that maps classes that extend Thing to handler functions:

```
interface ThingHandler {
    void handleThing(Thing thing);
}

Map<Class<? extends Thing>, ThingHandler> thingDispatch = new HashMap<>();
```

Add handlers to it that know how to handle each type of Thing:

```
thingDispatch.put(FooThing.class, new ThingHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handleThing(Thing thing) {
        // assume Thing is a FooThing by casting it
        FooThing fooThing = (FooThing) thing;
    }
});

// etc
thingDispatch.put(BarThing.class, new ThingHandler() { ... });
```

Now invoke it when you have a Thing to deal with:

```
Thing thing = ...;
thingDispatch.get(thing.getClass()).handleThing(thing);
```

Congrats, you've eliminated instanceof, at the expense of a bunch of extra lines of code!

I'll reserve judgement about which one is better in any given situation.

Comment: Thanks! But this is not the answer I was looking for. Is it just trade off between boilerplating and casting(instanceOf-ing). I think that this is indicator of a bad architecture in the library, not in my code

Comment: This pattern is actually quite common.  I honestly don't think you'll find an alternative in java.  Kotlin and Scala can ease the pain a bit, but they are just hiding the implementation details.